# How to use JSON variable of GET request in other HTTP request?

Tags: json, jmeter

I'm really new in JMeter.
Tenant has Multple Environments

[image]

I have a test plan to create a Tenant, Get the tenant list. And then i have a JSON Extractor to save the Tenantid in order to create automatly an Environment in the desired tenant.

JSON Extractor:

then I set a Header manager to use the ID of this tenant to create the Environment in the Tenant

[image]

My HTTP request is set like this 
[enter image description here][3]

But it doesn't work. Can you point me what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

1. Double check that your JSON Extractor works via [Debug Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) and [View Results Tree listener](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) combination. You should see `tenantId` variable value there. See [How to Debug your Apache JMeter Script](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script) article for more details.
2. If you **really** need to send `PATH` [HTTP Header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers) make HTTP Header Manager a child of the next HTTP Request sampler to avoid any clash with other HTTP Header Manager instances. Mind that [URL Path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier#Syntax) is not the same as HTTP Header named `PATH`
3. Check *jmeter.log* file for any suspicious entries.

Comment: Thanks it worked, Good advice to check the JSON is working.